# Javascript promise returning string from catch block

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the following Javascript Promise code.

```js
function job(state) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (state) {
      resolve('Promise success');
    } else {
      reject('Promise error');
    }
  });
}
let promise = job(true);
promise.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return job(false);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
  return 'Promise Error caught';
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return job(true);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The output running this code is as shown below;

```
Promise success
Promise error
Promise Error caught
```

Now my question is why/how does "Promise Error caught" get printed ? I would have thought that since it is a string, it would just return back and not execute any further code. But seems like that is not the case ?

Answer (score 2):

When inside a `.then` or a `.catch` block, if the interpreter reaches a `return` statement, the Promise of that block will resolve (not reject) to the value of what is returned.

The type of what is returned doesn't matter. It may be a string, or it may be a Promise (in which case that Promise will be unwrapped before the next `.then` executes), or it may be `undefined`.

Sure, it's often a bad idea to return something that isn't a Promise if you want to do more stuff with the value before finishing the Promise chain, but it doesn't result in an error - it just results in more noisy (and more difficult to understand) code.

```js
// Possible, but weird:
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(num => num + 1)
  .then(num => num * 2)
  .then(console.log);
  
setTimeout(() => {
  // Better:
  Promise.resolve(1)
    .then((num) => {
      const newNum = (num + 1) * 2;
      console.log(newNum);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hey....Quick question...So going by your logic, even within the first promise.then, we have a "return job(false)" ....And as you said "if the interpreter reaches a return statement, the Promise of that block will resolve (not reject) to the value" ....But here, the promise does not really "resolve", but is rejected

Comment: The returning of a Promise makes it a bit more complicated. If you don't return a Promise, it'll resolve. but if you return a Promise, it'll either resolve to the Promise's resolve value (if the Promise resolves), or it'll reject with the Promise's rejection reason (if the Promise rejects) - or it will hang forever, if the Promise never rejects or resolves.